# VERCEL BLOB CORRUPT FILES WITH NEXT JS 12

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, vercel

Estoy intentando subir archivos a Vercel blob pero cuando los reviso desde la interfaz de vercel aparacen corruptos, igual al intentar descargarlos. estoy usando next js, y el hosting tambien es de vercel, igual al tratar de subir via local tambien aparecen los archivos corruptos.

este es el codigo que uso para la subida de archivos:

Backend:

```
const form = new multiparty.Form();
  const { fields, files } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });

  const { photo } = files;
  const data = fields.data ? JSON.parse(fields.data[0]) : {};

  let url_image = null;
  if (photo && photo[0]) {
    const newFileName = `${Date.now()}.${photo[0].originalFilename
      .split(".")
      .pop()}`;
    const blob = await put(newFileName, photo[0], { access: "public" });
    url_image = blob.url;
  }
```

cliente:

```
const onFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      const currentFile = e.target.files[0];
      if (currentFile.type.includes("image")) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(currentFile);

        reader.onload = function load() {
          setPathImage(reader.result);
        };
        setFile(currentFile);
      } else {
        toast.warning("Please select a valid image");
      }
    }
  };
const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("photo", file);
      formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));

      const result = await axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
```